# Mobile Version Of My Web App With ZF2

Tags: mobile, view, zend-framework2, global, detect

I have developed a web application with zf2. And I have also developed it for mobile devices. 
But I cannot decide how can I pass this variable to controller visitor is mobile or not ... for example I want to reach to controller to isMobile or not from view.
Or do you suggest any other way?

```
//Application\Module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
    $mobileDetect = $serviceManager->get('MobileDetect'); //Retrieve "\Mobile_Detect" object

    //I want to reach to this value (isMobile or not) from my view. but how can do this?
        $isMobile = $mobileDetect->isMobile(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to access the `$isMobile` variable in the view files.

If that is so, then try this -

after `$isMobile = $mobileDetect->isMobile();`

write -

```
$e->getViewModel()->setVariables(
        array(
            'isMobile' => $isMobile,
        )
);
```

then in any view files, you can access it as `$isMobile` and you will get the set value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i can't reach isMobile variable in view. I think problem is new viewModel create in my controllers and isMobile variable lost. Is there any way?